# Edatabase error : Record not found while locating TTable ,

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, bde, locate

my application,  i have used TTable.locate option in many places to move the cursor, but in only one place it will raise "EDatabaseerror : Record Not Found',
aslo it will raise for particular records only,

The Locate Option only returns boolean value, if records exist it return True,if not it return Fasle, 
Why it raising Error?
am using:
Delphi 7, BDE5, Sql server 2008, am using Sql server native client driver to connect Sql server From BDE VIA ODBCE, application working fine except that place.

NOte:
am locting ttable using locaseinsensitive option, 
example :

```
tb_user.locate('username',tb_global_user.fieldbyname('Username',[locaseinsensitive]));
```

this error raised from my Result form, am  using this form for common search,
any helps ?

Comment: Show your real code, the one you posted does not even compile!. Being member for more than a year, please, learn how to properly format the code.

Comment: My guess is that you are using Master/Detail link.
You need to include the Master/Detail link field in the search criteria parameters "KeyFields" and  "KeyValues" as well as the value you are actually interested in finding. 
like this: `if Table2.Locate('LinkField;FindField',VarArrayOf([Table1['LinkValue'],Table3['FindValue']]),[]) 
then ... `